# How to find average of two gridviews in sql vb.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

I have two GridView1 and GridView2 which give a numerical values I want  to create another Gridview3 or functionality that can generate the average of both the values of the existing Gridview1 & GridView2 i.e. GridView3=(GridView1+GridView2)/2 
How should I write the SQL statement for it.

This is my GridView code in aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView7" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource9" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="mean_POLQA_score" HeaderText="mean_POLQA_score" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="mean_POLQA_score" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FAFAE7" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DAC09E" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E1DB9C" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#C2A47B" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

The SQL queries are as follows

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(POLQA_Score),3) AS mean_POLQA_score FROM VQTPOLQA WHERE VQT_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND VQuad_PhoneID =?

SELECT ROUND(AVG(POLQA_Score),3) AS mean_POLQA_score1 FROM VQTPOLQA WHERE VQT_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND VQuad_PhoneID =?
```

Comment: Is the problem generating the SQL query or you displaying it?

Comment: @Bojan Petkovic SQL query because I can display that query in the code as another GridView3

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the two SQL queries you are using to populate the grids?

Comment: @chrisuae Yeah thanks for the advice added the queries

Comment: It looks like these queries return a single value each, so why do you need a grid?  If you have a reason for using grids, [this may help.](https://forums.asp.net/t/1596173.aspx?how+to+take+value+from+a+cell+in+gridview+using+vb+net)

Comment: I need a grid to display the average of these values